# How to attach storyboard window to main window in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, ios10

I have recently started learning IOS development and I am having a minor issue. When I launched Xcode I can see that when I click storyboard a separate window pops up, whereas in case of the tutorial the storyboard window is attached to the Xcode window.
How can I attach the storyboard window to Xcode window?

Comment: Don't use double click. just one click on it. double click opens it in another window.

Comment: It worked, thanks for the help.